# Менять цвет каждого слова на С++ ?

Tags: c++

Менять цвет каждого слова на С++ в косольных програмах

Answer (score 5):

В случае `Windows` это делается следующим образом:

```
#include <windows.h>
// '7' - номер соответствующего цвета, поддерживаемого консолью.
::SetConsoleTextAttribute(::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
```

В случае `*nix` достаточно просто воспользоваться `ANSI Color Codes`, подробнее можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal)

---

*Как вариант "не на коленке" могу также предложить для этих целей библиотеку [**Ncurses.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)*

Comment: ncurses немного для других целей предназначен. Оптимальный вариант для никсов - управляющие последовательности.

Comment: Дополню: *ncurses* предназначен для создания в консоли оконного пользовательского интерфейса.